# How to print out the number of times a certain number appears in an array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the number of times `55` appears in an array.

I tried using a condition to state that if the number is % by 5, to print 2. I also incorporated a break. This is what I have:

```
def virus(array)
  index = 0
  array.length.times do
    if array[index] % 5
      p 2
      break
    end
    index = index + 1
  end
end

p virus([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44])
```

My output is supposed to be 2, but I get `2` and `nil`.

Comment: Did you notice there's a missing `end` keyword in the code you added?

Comment: I have edited your code sample to add indentation and add the missing `end`. It's really important that when you post a question on stackoverflow that your code sample be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- that includes indentation. It doesn't make sense to make it harder for people to read your code. Remember that you're asking volunteers for help.

Comment: If you don't want simply `[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44].count(55) #=> 2` you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a fix for your code, since you have `p 2` to print 2 instead of a counter:

```
def virus(array)
  index = 0
  count = 0
  array.length.times do
    if array[index]%5 == 0
      count +=1
    end
    index = index + 1
  end
  return count
end
```

You need to add a `count` variable to be increased if the element is divisible by 5 (`if array[index]%5 == 0`) or maybe you need to check if element equals 55..

There is no need to break, or you are missing some elements to count. Also the `break` returns `nil`, that's why it is printed out.

Finally you need to return the count.

Building a custom loop is a useful way to learn, but I also suggest you take a look at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count, just to use Ruby build in methods:

```
array = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44]
array.count { |e| e % 5 == 0 } #=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44].count(55)
# => 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `p virus([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44])`
try puts:

```
def virus(array)
  index = 0
  array.length.times do
    if array[index] % 5
      puts 2
      break
    end
    index = index + 1
  end
end
puts virus([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44])
```

It will return 2 only...

Comment: This is wrong; it returns 2 and `nil` and the final return value is `nil`. Run your answer in IRB; you'll see `=> nil`.

Comment: @anothermh: Please read @cholis's question carefully. He is getting 2 and nil at same time as an output. You can try the same code with `puts virus([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 66, 55, 44])` at line https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/ 
It will return nil in the next line but  it wont return nil along with 2 at a time. Before down-voting, please verify correctly from  your end..  you can run the code here also:   http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/ebc5d

Comment: Have you not run this yourself? The **return value** of both the `p` and `puts` versions you've shown is `nil`, but in your answer you say "_It will **return** 2_". You are wrong and this answer is wrong. Try running the [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898597/3784008), which is correct.